# Can i edit Xeror printer colour profile on OSX to make all colours / white points 10% lighter?

Tags: printing, printer, colors

Ive got a Xerox 6515 printer.

The printer is supposed to be able to print Pantone colours, but i always feel its 10% too dark.

Ive played around with loads of colour profiles and settings, but i cant get the colours to look right.

Ive got a ICM profile file for the printer, is there a way i can edit this to make it 10% lighter across the board ? Perhaps by setting the white point to have 10% less black ?

Im on a Mac running OSX 10.14.6 which has the OSX inbuilt colour sync tool, but i cant see anywhere to edit the profiles.

Upon consideration the printer is probably behaving correctly , and most probably it my screen that’s too bright. I do have a screen calibration tool, but rarely use it for day to day work. Instead of calibrating my screen to the printer, I’d like to adjust the ICM profile to have my printer closer match the screen.

I don’t need to print Pantone colours, so was just using it as a reference for this conversation.

---

Alternatively after some digging I found a GUI that will let me do this in the print dialog, but i can only seem to access this GUI when printing via MS word on OSX, if i get to the print dialog via OSX Preview i get a different GUI. (see attached screenshots)

[image: GUI via OSX preview]

[image: GUI via MS word on OSX]

Comment: "10% too dark" compared to what? A current Pantone book [they only have a 2-year life-span] or your screen? Is your screen calibrated accurately & have you calibrated your workflow to the printer, using the appropriate colorimeter/spectrophotometer?

Comment: @Tetsujin good point, I’ve updated me to question for more info / background

Comment: If you have physical pantone samples (just to say), you can print the same color and compare it with the references. Of course, it is good practice to first adjust the brightness and temperature of the screen to match the physical references (pantone). Then to adjust the printer to match the same physical references (pantone). I talked about reference**s** because obviously it is better to have more than one ... If you insist on matching the _altered_ screen with the printer, you can try to modify the "lightness" indicator in the GUI, directly, until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools that let you create and edit ICC or ICM files. However, to match screen and printer you will need hardware (spectrophotometer) as well as software tools: you need to measure the output on the screen and on the paper. Also, remember that the printed colour will vary depending on the paper type (let alone colour) used.

Start by having a look at http://color.org/profilingtools.xalter

Popular hardware is available from [X-Rite](https://www.xrite.com/categories) and others.

Comment: Ive had a look at some of those profile tools, but cant seem to find one that will let me edit an existing profile like the existing xerox profile i have to amend it as described in the question, for instance that document lists photoshop as being able to edit the ICM / ICC files but i cant actually see how to do this, when looking online it photoshop seems more able to edit its own created ICC profiles than anything else. Ive had a look at x-Rite but unless im mistaken i think all their software is proprietary and quite expensive

Comment: I don't think there is a cheap solution to editing icc/icm files. The only thing I have some remote experience with is X-Rite and their Profilemaker (which is no longer available and replaced by i1Publish). See https://www.xrite.com/search?search=profilemaker

Answer (score 0):

You could try the color profiles available
[from Xerox](https://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-6515/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=win10x64#mainForm:catId-4),
to see if they do the printing better.
Installing the profiles is described in the article
[How to Install ICC Color Profiles Mac OSX](https://www.redrivercatalog.com/profiles/how_to_install_ICC_color_profiles_mac_apple.html).

You could also try the free
[Gutenprint and Gimp-Print software](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php)
for Mac OS X, which supports Xerox although your exact printer model is not in
the list.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried the colour profiles available from Xerox, but they hardly make a noticeable difference